# Set flag type task level enterprise custom field using VBA

Tags: vba, ms-project

I want to set flag type enterprise custom field at the task level to True/False Or Yes/No. May I know the syntax for the same in VBA.

The MSDN says:

> ```
> projectField = FieldNameToFieldConstant("TestEntProjText", pjProject)
>
> ActiveProject.ProjectSummaryTask.SetField FieldID:=projectField, Value:="This is a new value."
> ```

where Value is a string. But in my case I want it to be a boolean value.

Answer (score 0):

The `SetField` method always takes a string value but can be used to set any field. Use "Yes" and "No" to set Boolean values.

The related method `GetField` returns a field value as it is displayed in the table view and thus always returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

Sub setEnterpriseFlag()

```
Dim myTask As Task
Set myTask = ActiveProject.Tasks.Item(1)

Debug.Print myTask.GetField(pjTaskEnterpriseFlag1)
Debug.Print myTask.GetField(pjTaskEnterpriseFlag2)

myTask.SetField pjTaskEnterpriseFlag1, boolToStr_forSetField(True)
myTask.SetField pjTaskEnterpriseFlag2, boolToStr_forSetField(False)

Debug.Print myTask.GetField(pjTaskEnterpriseFlag1)
Debug.Print myTask.GetField(pjTaskEnterpriseFlag2)
```

End Sub

'Unfortunately task.SetField and task.GetField deal only with strings. An easy
'way to manage this would be to use a simple wrapper function.
Function boolToStr_forSetField(boolVal As Boolean) As String
    If boolVal Then
        boolToStr_forSetField = "Yes"
    Else
        boolToStr_forSetField = "No"
    End If
End Function